# Оцифровка VHS-видео с помощью аудиокарты ПК

Tags: аудио, видео, преобразование, обработка-сигналов

Есть такой вопрос: покупать ТВ-тюнер или подобные устройства для того, чтобы оцифровать одну видеокассету не очень-то и хочется. Но у меня имеется кабель "Два RCA-Колокольчика для видео и аудио - jack 3.5", который можно подключить к компьютеру через аудиовход для микрофона.
Используя этот метод, прекрасно записывается звук с видеокассеты, если я использую только аудиовыход видеомагнитофона. Но мне нужно видео, и вот что происходит:

Если я подключаю "колокольчик" RCA к видеовыходу видеомагнитофона, то при воспроизведении видеокассеты на ПК я отчётливо вижу аналоговый сигнал, идущий в разъём микрофона. Спектрограмма подтверждает, что это не шум - это действительно меняющийся сигнал, он меняется с течением времени, обрывается при окончании воспроизведения и т.п..

Я не совсем разбираюсь в устройстве кодирования видеосигнала на видеокассетах, описание этой технологии на немногочисленных сайтах весьма поверхностны.

Можно ли каким-либо образом найти программу, умеющую декодировать этот сигнал (например, сохранённый в формат .wav без потерь) в видео-поток, либо же самостоятельно спроектировать её, или это вовсе невозможно из-за ограничения поддерживаемой частоты входного сигнала аудиокарты компьютера?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Только вот смотрите - аудиопоток имеет меньшую скорость потока данных в кбит/сек. И звуковая карта с ее частотой дискредитации с такой нагрузкой справляется. Видеопоток - на порядок и даже больше выше скорость потока. Звуковая карта по своим техническим характеристикам не сможет с ним справиться. Тем более встроенная - у нее дискредитация обычно в 3 раза ниже чем у дискретной. Видеосигнал закодирован, и если даже получить 10% от него, раскодировать не получится. Погуглите "video capture via sound card" - я ничего не нашел.

Comment: Если речь идёт о передачи видео по одному каналу, то это композитный видеоинтерфейс: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video

Comment: В интернетах [пишут](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/composite-video-signal), что частота для оцифровки композитного видеосингала должна превышать 10 МГц — вероятно, именно это и является ограничивающим фактором

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Всё понял. Придётся всё-таки тюнер покупать)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал поискать на барахолках цифровую видеокамеру формата Di8 с убитым лентопротягом и возможностью сквозной оцифровки. По опыту, цифрует с VHS лучше любых, даже достаточно дорогих, тюнеров.